# Why does 0.43 convert to 43?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, decimal

Why is Cbm filled with 43 and not 0,43

```
string strCbm;
decimal Cbm;

strCbm = unConvertedCbm.CustomValue.Replace(".", ",");
Cbm = (Quantity * Decimal.Parse(strCbm));
```

For your information:

`unConvertedCbm.CustomValue` = filled with 0.43

`Quantity` = filled with 1

**I will describe this code next:**

1. I create a string and a decimal.
2. I replace all '.' in CustomValue with a ','.
3. CustomValue gets inserted into strCbm, with 0.43 converted to 0,43.
4. Cbm gets filled with Quantity(1) multiplied by 0,43(Converted to a
   decimal)

Cbm should be 0,43 in my opinion and not 43.

Why is Cbm filled with 43 and not 0,43?

Comment: Don't do this: `unConvertedCbm.CustomValue.Replace(".", ",");`. Do `Decimal.Parse(new CultureInfo("someculturegoeshere"))`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because the decimal separator of your culture is the `,` and not the `.` probably. Try doing `(0.5).ToString()` and see if you have your result as `0.5` or `0,5`.

The truth is that you shouldn't use the `Replace`, you should do:

```
var culture = new CultureInfo("someculturegoeshere");
```

and then

```
Decimal Cbm = Decimal.Parse(strCbm, culture);
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't thought about the culture problem, it is true that I changed from English to Dutch culture in the application. Will accept answer, when I can:)

Answer (score 1):

It's because your culture recognizes the '.' symbol as a decimal point, not the ',' symbol. You can use the CultureInfo class to convert the decimal to the desired culture.

For example, if you want to use the french format, you can do:

```
Decimal.Parse(strCbm, new CultureInfo("fr-FR"));
```

And so on.

Answer (score 0):

You can read the details about it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ew0seb73.aspx). You can do this

```
string value;
NumberStyles style;
CultureInfo culture;
decimal number;            
value = "0,43";
style = NumberStyles.Number | NumberStyles.AllowCurrencySymbol;
culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("fr-FR");
if (Decimal.TryParse(value, style, culture, out number))
     Console.WriteLine("Converted '{0}' to {1}.", value, number);
else
     Console.WriteLine("Unable to convert '{0}'.", value);
```